# How to order by clause with distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in sql server in which I have some values. For example as below

```
Transaction   ProductNo
------------- -------------
2001-01-01          1
2001-01-01          3
2001-01-01          4
2001-01-02          2
2001-01-02          3
2001-01-02          5
```

I have written a query as below

```
SELECT DISTINCT trans.[Transaction], 
STUFF(( SELECT ',' + trans1.ProductNo  AS [text()] FROM Transactions trans1 
WHERE trans.[Transaction]=trans1.[Transaction] ORDER BY trans1.[Transaction] FOR XML PATH('')), 1,1,'')[ProductNo] 
FROM Transactions trans
```

output as below:

```
Transaction   ProductNo
------------- -------------
2001-01-01        1,3,4
2001-01-02        2,3,5
```

but I am getting below exception

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ',' to data type int.
```

Comment: I'm assuming `ProductNo` is an `INT`?, so, how do you want to concatenate it with a `','` without converting it first?. Use `SELECT ',' + CAST(trans1.ProductNo AS VARCHAR(5))` or similar

Comment: Thank @Lamak I done it

Answer (score 2):

`',' + trans1.ProductNo` - here is the problem. SQL server thinks you are trying to add a comma to a number. Try changing `trans1.ProductNo`to `CAST(trans1.ProductNo AS VARCHAR)`.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to convert your int column to a string in order to concatenate. Otherwise it is trying to turn your comma into an int which it can't.

STR() documentation to convert numbers to strings: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527.aspx)

See new query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT trans.[Transaction], 
STUFF(( SELECT ',' + str(trans1.ProductNo)  AS [text()] FROM Transactions trans1 
WHERE trans.[Transaction]=trans1.[Transaction] ORDER BY trans1.[Transaction] FOR     XML PATH('')), 1,1,'')[ProductNo] 
FROM Transactions trans
```